# Adding setter behaviour to dependency properties

Tags: wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties

We are advised not to add behaviour to accessor methods of dependency property wrappers because they can be bypassed by a direct call to Get/SetValue.

OK, that's reasonable. So where *do* we put this behaviour?

We can supply a `ValidateValueCallback` delegate while registering the dependency property. This calls a static method of our provenance that takes a single parameter object value, sufficient for context independent checks like "seconds must be in the range 0-59".

Sometimes you need instance dependent context information, eg the valid range of Day depends on the instance value of Month.

What are we supposed to do in this case? This would be trivial to handle in the propdp setter.

It has been proposed below that the PropertyChanged event might be used for this kind of validation, and this is in fact what I did in the circumstance that prompted this question. However, this is ugly because at this stage the change has been committed to the model, so it is necessary to maintain an undo stack to provide access to the prior value.

There does seem to be some material in MSDN on this very topic, but I have not had time to give it the consideration it needs.

Comment: Could you not just use the `PropertyChanged` event in the Properties metadata when registering the property to handle all that logic, as that passes in the owner and changed values (oldvalue, new value)

Comment: Perhaps, but that occurs *after* the value is committed to the model, so for that to work I would have to go the whole hog and implement commands and an undo stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found a solution, `CoerceValueCallback` runs before the property is change and you can intercept and change the value if needed before its passed on any further.

Perhaps you could try this and see if it works in your situation.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0, null, new CoerceValueCallback(CoercePropertyValue)));

private static object CoercePropertyValue(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    if (This != That)
    {
        return value;
    }
    return 6;
}
```

Comment: A cursory inspection of the related msdn information makes me think you're onto something. When I get home I'll look into it.

Comment: It's untidy if you ask me but it works and it's even an officially blessed approach.